# ABAP Select fields with count > 1

Tags: abap, opensql

Is there any way to select some fields from BSID where the combination of BUKRS-KUNNR-DMBTR is greater than 1. I thought that the below select will work, but it doesn't.

```
SELECT bukrs kunnr dmbtr COUNT(*)
      INTO TABLE git_double
    FROM bsid
    WHERE bukrs = '1000' AND
          blart = 'WP'   AND
          budat IN s_budat AND
          gjahr IN s_gjahr AND
          count(*) > 1
    GROUP BY bukrs kunnr dmbtr.
```

Is there any way to do this in 1 selection?
Thanks

Comment: Check the SQL clause HAVING...

Comment: Thanks, I completely had forgoten the clause HAVING. The only difference is that in our version the correct is:  **HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1.**, space before and after asterisk (*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selections on [aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) like `COUNT` can be done inside the [`HAVING`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)) clause

```
  SELECT bukrs kunnr dmbtr COUNT(*)
    INTO TABLE git_double
      FROM bsid
      WHERE bukrs = '1000' AND
            blart = 'WP'   AND
            budat IN s_budat AND
            gjahr IN s_gjahr
      GROUP BY bukrs kunnr dmbtr
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1.        " <==== HAVING after GROUP BY
```

For information, from ABAP 7.40 SP05, you may also write it by using [host variables](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenopensql_strict_modes.htm):

```
  SELECT bukrs, kunnr, dmbtr, COUNT(*) AS accd_count
    INTO TABLE @DATA(git_double)
      FROM bsid
      WHERE bukrs = '1000' AND
            blart = 'WP'   AND
            budat IN @s_budat AND
            gjahr IN @s_gjahr
      GROUP BY bukrs, kunnr, dmbtr
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1.
```

Comment: This is the correct but in our old version we need it in the old way.

Comment: EDIT: I updated the answer to focus on the old version used in the question